# Django RawSql Annotate

Tags: python, sql, django, annotate

I'm new to Django so I will have ask some help. I have a table with records representing Transit. When transit arrives to depot, I need to find how many Resources are that time in depot. Resource has start time and end time. What I need to do, is annotate Resources count to Transit using Transit depot arrival time. There is now any relation between models.

I think I might need RawSql for this but I'm still little short of knowledge to do this.

```
#models.py
class Transit(models.Model):
    depot_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    depot_arrival=models.DateField()


class Resource(models.Model):
    resource_id=models.PositiveIntegerField()
    shift_start=models.DateField()
    shift_end=models.DateField()

#views.py
class TransitView(TableViewMixin)

   def get_queryset(self):
       Transit.objects.annotate(
           resources_count=RawSql('Select...')
       )
```

Comment: Don't tell us, show us. You have a table, so show us the table definition. Show sample data, show sample expected output, and then show the code you already wrote that did not produce the correct results.

Comment: Updated some source code